# Create or open a database table in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

If I use the below code:

```
var db = openDatabase("CurrADinfo", "1", "A list of QC Points.", 100000);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE foo (id , text)');
});
```

It will create or open the database `CurrADinfo` if it exists. But the second line will always create a new table.

I want to create a table once and next time when I try to create it should return a flag that it is found in the database. How can I do that?

Comment: openDatabase will open the database if it exists, or create a new one if it does not. I'm not sue what you need past that.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question has to do with HTML5.  Help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question (which isn't completely clear to me), you need to create a table if one doesn't already exist:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id , text)');
```